# Number of items in a list is not correct python

Tags: python, list

I have a text file of tweets like the following:

```
1   1   Sweet United Nations video. Just in time for Christmas. #imagine #NoReligion 
2   1   @mrdahl87 We are rumored to have talked to Erv..that's hardly nothing    ;)
3   1   Hey there! Nice to see you Winter Weather 
4   0   3 episodes left I'm dying over here
```

and I have this code:

```
import csv

with open('./data/train.txt',encoding="utf8") as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t')
    col1 = list(zip(*reader))[0]

c = 0
for x in col1:
    c = c+1
    print(x , "  " , c)
```

When I print the length of my list it shows 3817, but the real number of items are 3834 !!
I added a counter "C" to check and counting process and it also gave me 3817 !!

I checked the file manually by printing the line:

```
file_lines  counter_c
1643        1643
1644        1644
1645        1645
1649        1646 <-----
1650        1647
```

I found that some lines the file reader skipped them like 1646, 1647, 1648 !!

And they are these line:

```
1645    0   "@SchmidtSTL: Thanks to @automaticg. I think I backed into the playoffs! Playoff matchup: TacoCorp v Gronkey Punch 
1646    0   oh yeah,  its official #im  #crazy htt.co/bgcLDJQIR6
1647    1   Oh well, looks like we are back to square 1. Batie and Bridge. This is going to go so well    #BoldandBeautiful
1648    1   "@antoineraps: @edifyin how are you up now? Ho!"
```

What is the problem ?!

Editted (tweet 1645 added)

I found that there is something wrong in tweet 1645 ! what is it?
or how can I solve it in reading the text?

Comment: Line 1645 seems to be missing a trailing double-quote.

Comment: thanx, The problem is because of the first comma, I test it now !
How I can solve it in code, since that some tweets are contains such cases!?

Comment: Try `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`.

Comment: Thanx , its work